# Get code to run on every column in a table -Error "Could not find a public static method named ..." -Mapbasic 17

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic, regular-expression

I need to run a table update command on every column in a table. The code works fine when I manually define the column to work in but not when it is part of a for loop that gets all the column names I get
[image]

If I take the update table command out of the loop and into the code after the for loop, it works fine.

**What's different with defining a declare for use in a loop?**

```
'64 bit regex based on https://community.pitneybowes.com/communities/communityhome/digestviewer/viewthread?MessageKey=a92a0fcd-5348-4eae-aa93-a47d5a1e6bbe&CommunityKey=3c2aca7a-c3ae-4602-a142-9ee956769d55&tab=digestviewer#bma92a0fcd-5348-4eae-aa93-a47d5a1e6bbe'
Include "MapBasic.def"

'64 bit regex'
Declare Method RegExReplace Class "WindowHelper.Controller" Lib "WindowHelper.dll" (ByVal sInput As String, ByVal sPattern As String, ByVal sReplace As String) As String

Declare Method RegExIsMatch Class "WindowHelper.Controller" Lib "WindowHelper.dll" (ByVal sInput As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As Logical

Declare Method RegExFirstMatch Class "WindowHelper.Controller" Lib "WindowHelper.dll" (ByVal sInput As String, ByVal sPattern As String) As String

Declare Sub Main

Sub Main
    Dim inFile, regexString as String
    Dim inColumn as Alias

    inFile= "Z:\My Drive\Mangoesmapping\Spatial Projects\2018\DSC\007_DSC_Asset_Identification_and_Geocoding\Working\Phase3_DataEnrichment\Working\DataUpdates\Scratch\Water_Hydrants.TAB"

    'Perform Regex and text Replace'
    Open Table inFile as tempTable
    'Alter Table tempTable (add ScratchField Char(254) ) Interactive
    Browse * From tempTable
    regexString ="^\s\|\s(.*)"

    ' Perform on all fields -ref: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75494/how-to-loop-through-all-columns-in-a-table-layer-getting-all-data-for-a-row-feat    
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim aCol As Alias
    Dim nCol As Integer
    For nCol = 1 To TableInfo(tempTable, TAB_INFO_NCOLS)
        sCol = ColumnInfo(tempTable, "COL" & nCol, COL_INFO_NAME)
        aCol = tempTable & "." & sCol
    'Update every column as it's found --- GIVES ERROR          
        'Update tempTable Set ScratchField = RegExReplace(aCol,regexString,"")      
        Next        
    'Update a known column
    inColumn = tempTable & ".As_con_3_hyperlink"
    Update tempTable Set ScratchField = RegExReplace(inColumn,regexString,"")           
End Sub
```

UPDATED CODE based on T_Bacon's input.

Had to change scratchField to aCol as it is now checking every column.

```
Sub Main
    Dim inFile, inField, regexString, strValue as String

    inFile = "Z:\My Drive\Mangoesmapping\Spatial Projects\2018\DSC\007_DSC_Asset_Identification_and_Geocoding\Working\Phase3_DataEnrichment\Working\DataUpdates\Scratch\Water_Hydrants.TAB"
    inField = ".As_con_3_hyperlink"
    'Perform Regex and text Replace'
    Open Table inFile as tempTable
    'Alter Table tempTable (add ScratchField Char(254) ) Interactive
    Browse * From tempTable
    'Pattern for starting | without anything before it
    regexString ="(.*)[\s]+\|\s(.*)"

    ' Perform on all fields -ref: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/75494/how-to-loop-through-all-columns-in-a-table-layer-getting-all-data-for-a-row-feat    
    Dim sCol As String
    Dim aCol As Alias
    Dim nCol As Integer
    For nCol = 1 To TableInfo(tempTable, TAB_INFO_NCOLS)
        sCol = ColumnInfo(tempTable, "COL" & nCol, COL_INFO_NAME)
        aCol = tempTable & "." & sCol
    'Update every column as it's found --- GIVES ERROR ref: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/316048/get-code-to-run-on-every-column-in-a-table-error-could-not-find-a-public-stati       
        strValue = aCol
        Update tempTable Set aCol = RegExReplace(strValue, regexString, "")         
        Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably not working because you are passing it the **alias** variables `acol` and `inColumn` and it is expecting a **string**. Try storing the required parameters into a string variable and passing that to the function.

e.g.

```
strValue = aCol
Update tempTable Set sCol = RegExReplace(strValue, regexString, "")
```

Comment: The issue is that aCol and inColumn (which are basically the same) have to be alias values as they are the names of a column. You can't pass just the name of a column as a string into an update table command (I tried earlier) - see http://support.pitneybowes.com/VFP05_KnowledgeWithSidebarHowTo?id=kA180000000CtKHCA0&popup=false&lang=en_US 
Also it works fine as an alias (inColumn) when you run the update command outside of the for loop (line before End Sub). So the issue is probably something in the declare for the regex command not being recognized in the for loop...

Comment: Yes, but you are not using the alias column directly in the update statement, you are passing it as a parameter to a function that returns a value to the update statement. The update is only concerned with the value returned by the function, it has no visibility of the alias variable. The function doesn't want an alias variable, but a string, so it would seem to me that's where your problem lies. I've updated my answer to show how it could be written.

Comment: I now get Expression doesn't evaluate to column or table name. I'll put the modified code in the Q.

Comment: Instead of using `aCol` in the update statement, try using sCol. I think the update statement just wants the column name as you've already specified what table with `tempTable`. I've updated my answer with the change.